Using state machines instead of coroutines
Within my Unity game I have various NPCs that do different tasks at different times. Everything is coded using coroutines as it's all I knew when starting out. The NPC will use a coroutine to decide on a task, then execute the coroutine associated with the task, then start the ChoosingTask() coroutine again. Rinse and repeat. Everything functions as it should. My question is: is it beneficial to me to rewrite everything using a state machine? Are there performance downsides to using coroutines for everything they do? It seems much clearer from a development standpoint when using a state machine, but if everything works as it should, are there any major downsides in my method?

I'm aware this is a bit of a noobie question. But it will take a chunk of time for me to rewrite everything using a state machine, as it's something I'm still learning about. So I'm curious to know if it's something worth putting my time into, if the result is essentially the same. Any advice is appreciated :)

If it works and you have no performance problems then don't worry about it. In general though, every time you spin a coroutine it allocates an object and if you do it very often (like many times a second) then it could be a problem.

While im also with the camp of "if it aint broke, dont fix it", state machines are well worth learning.   If are in the mood and want to apply state machines, now is a good time to try it

One potential downside of using Coroutines is that they are not serializable and therefore cannot be included in saves. By coding state machines by hand, you could make the states serializable.
Performance wise, it should not make a significant difference. Coroutines rely on resumable iterator functions which are just compiler-generated state machines, so it's basically the same thing as instantiating your own state machine.

This is true to some extend. It's possible with a lot of reflection to serialize a coroutine. Though what you will loose is the current progress in something like a WaitForSeconds. So the last yield is essentially skipped when loaded back. Though it's probably not worth to serialize coroutines as you're stuck with their limitations. A custom state machine would make more sense in that case, like you said.
